# PDO Fetch Largest Value

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, pdo

I have been researching for the past hour with no luck, i've tried so many methods. All I want to do to is get the largest value from a certain column in a table and store it in a variable in php that I can use for whatever I want. Here's where I'm at so far:

```
$link = new PDO('mysql:host=****;dbname=****;charset=UTF-8','****','****');
$gid = $link->prepare("SELECT MAX(Group_ID) as maxGroup FROM Conference");
$gid->execute();
$test = $gid->fetch(PDO::OBJ);
echo $test;
```

At this point I don't even know if OBJ is correct, I'm just trying so many different things. Can anyone help me out, what do I need to do? I just want to get the largest value and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning an object, so you need to access the properties accordingly:

```
echo $test->maxGroup;
```

The `->fetch(PDO::OBJ);` returns the results of the query and creates an object with properties based on the columns/aliases you have in your query.

Edit: If you are just trying to return the results and trying a few different ways, why not just do it in a simple way:

```
$test = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $test['maxGroup'];
```

Comment: @Richard Seems I had the uppercase wrong, but I also gave you an alternative to try.

Answer (score 3):

Why not directly association?

```
$link = new PDO('mysql:host=****;dbname=****;charset=UTF-8','****','****');
$gid = $link->prepare("SELECT MAX(Group_ID) as maxGroup FROM Conference");
$gid->execute();
$test = $gid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $test['maxGroup'];
```

Answer (score 0):

i  create a  simple  function  for  who want to  use  it  simple  but  helpfull
for the  pdo() it's  a  simple  function i know from my heart  that  you know what  i mean  with  it

```
function last_inserted($column,$table){
 $dbh = pdo();
 $gid = $dbh->prepare("SELECT MAX(".$column.") as maxGroup FROM ".$table);
 $gid->execute();
 $last = $gid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 return $last['maxGroup'];
 }
```